# Error 404 when trying to install arduino on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, installation

I'm facing some problems when trying to install arduino on ubuntu.

I have tried installing it via ubuntu software center, but it aborted and displayed an error message "check your Internet connection".

So i tried installing it through the terminal with " sudo apt-get install arduino" and i noticed that it wasn't loading and it keeps printing "error 404 not found..." and "failed to fetch..."

I ended up downloading the file from the arduino website itself but after that i couldn't seem to find the application !

Am i missing something ? Or did i do something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think their server is experiencing some issues...